# firebug says my function never ran - can't figure out why

Tags: jquery

When I submit `#top_cat`, the firebug console says `"ok"` because of the debug text I'm printing here:

```
function submitHandler() {
    console.log("ok");
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
    return false;
}
```

But if I click on `#tip_click`, I see `"start"` and `"end"` in the output but it never says `"ok"` - meaning the `submitHandler` never ran.

Is there anything obviously wrong with this code?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#top_cat').submit(submitHandler);

    $("#tip_click").click(function() {
        console.log("start");
        $("#high_hat").submit(submitHandler);
        console.log("end");
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#high_hat").submit(submitHandler);
```

This registers an `onsubmit` handler but does not run the handler. It sets up the handler to be called whenever `#high_hat` is submitted. If you want to run the submit handler right away you'll need to trigger it yourself by calling `submit()` (no arguments):

```
console.log("start");
$("high_hat").submit(submitHandler).submit();
console.log("end");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try:

```
$("#tip_click").click(function() {
        console.log("start");
        submitHandler();
        console.log("end);
});
```

I don't see any benefit to submitting it manually, since it returns false anyway, so just calling the submitHandler directly will simplify the code.

I don't see any benefit to submitting as John suggests since you return false anyway.

Comment: I was going to suggest this but he uses `$(this)` inside `submitHandler`.